# Adding select2 jquery component to SharePoint Framework (SPFx) web part

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

I am having trouble incorporating Select2 into my SharePoint web part.  I'm not sure which module to install from npm, or how to include the appropriate references in my typescript file.

Using straight script and css references won't work because it doesn't know how to interpret the initiation:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-example-basic-single').select2();  <-- fails
});
```

https://select2.org/getting-started/installation

Answer (score 1):

There is an official tutorial explaining how to incorporate jQueryUI accordion component in SPFx. Adding select2 is pretty much the same.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/add-jqueryui-accordion-to-web-part

One of the ways:

1. Add jQuery and Select2. The @type files are optional (provide auto-complete support in particular), but it's easier to have them than not to have:

```
> npm i jquery select2 
> npm i @types/jquery @types/select2 --save-dev
```

2. Add jquery and seelct2 to `config/config.json` (so that they are included by the spfx build, i.e. by the webpack):

```json
  ...
  "externals": {
    "jquery": "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "select2": "node_modules/select2/dist/js/select2.js"
  },
  ...
```

3. Use them in your webpart. Assuming you start with "minimal" web part:

```js
import { Version } from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';
import { BaseClientSideWebPart } from '@microsoft/sp-webpart-base';

import 'jquery';
import 'select2';

import '../../../node_modules/select2/dist/css/select2.css';

export interface IHelloWorldWebPartProps {
}

export default class HelloWorldWebPart 
  extends BaseClientSideWebPart<IHelloWorldWebPartProps> {

  public render(): void {
    this.domElement.innerHTML = `
      <select class="js-example-basic-single" name="state">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
      </select>
    `;

    // the below line works now, but breaks the "rule"
    // taht webpart should not go beyond the parent node:
    // 
    //    $(".js-example-basic-single").select2();
    // 
    // using web part root as dropdown parent may be a bit safer:
    // 
    $(".js-example-basic-single").select2({
      dropdownParent: $(this.domElement)
    });
  }

  protected onInit(): Promise<void> {
    return super.onInit();
  }

  protected get dataVersion(): Version {
    return Version.parse('1.0');
  }
}
```

BTW maybe you could use a [Fluent UI](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/pickers) component instead of Select2, its style will be matching the other Microsoft controls on the page, you'll get theming support out of the box. But it depends on the nature of your project of course.

Other than that, you would probably want to use minified (.min.js and .min.css) versions of the files for production.